# How to set values by default using checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm using a `Map` to store the state of my checkboxes. My current component has 3 sections. In each section I have checkboxes. I would like to set these values by default:

```
const defaultOptions = [
    { label: "Mark", value: "mark" },
    { label: "Steve", value: "steve" },
    { label: "Paul", value: "Paul" }
];
```

How can I use this array and set values by default? Thanks in advance!

Here's a live [**DEMO**](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-helloworld-forked-mr3ggl?file=/src/components/Post.tsx:268-412)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can aggregate the values in the array into a `Map` based on the post label.

```js
setCheckboxStates(defaultOptions.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const key = someJson.find(p => p.fields.some(f => f.name === curr.label)).label;
  if (!acc.has(key)) acc.set(key, []);
  acc.get(key).push(curr);
  return acc;
}, new Map()));
```

Comment: [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-helloworld-forked-dn64zc?file=/src/App.tsx:577-633)